# Rainbow: Making a Bracha on a bad Omen

Tags: halacha, blessing, see-sight-vision-blind, weather, natural-phenomenon

As discussed in [some earlier questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10065/641) Rainbows are a bad Omen yet we are Halachicly commanded to make a Bracha on it. [The Gemara in Chagigah (16A)](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1559&size=2) says you may not gaze at one so how do you make the Bracha on the bad omen you are not supposed to look at?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not supposed to gaze at it, however if you notice it you make a Bracha.

**When one sees a rainbow a bracha should be made.  However, one should be careful not to stare at a rainbow for too long (Orach Chaim 229:1).**

The Be'er Hataiv 2 in Orach Chaim 229:1 says that looking at a rainbow weakens the eyes.

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=283

Comment: As does the Gemara in Chagiga (16A): http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1559&size=2

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10963/603