# Meaning of a Double Rainbow

Tags: number, weather, symbols-symbology

After my mum died and while we were planning for her funeral, during one dramatic day after we had left the funeral home, my dad and I saw a giant double rainbow in the sky.  I understand that single rainbows are a sign of God's covenant with us.  But, can you please tell me what a double rainbow is a sign of?  Is there something in the Torah or in any other Jewish writings that provides an understanding of the meaning of a double rainbow?

Comment: Also, I should say that the double rainbow was a complete arc and it looked like it was just over my parent's property.

Comment: My condolences on the loss of your mother. [May God comfort you, among the rest of those who mourn Zion and Jerusalem.](http://chabad.org/300864)

Answer (score 4):

> The [Seforno on Bereishis 9:17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=141) understands the double rainbow as a wakeup call
>   for Noach and his family “to [spiritually] wake up on seeing it, and
>   to awaken the people of the generation to repent, to be wise, and to
>   do good.” The Sages in several places caution against staring at the
>   rainbow, based on a mystical understanding of the rainbow's
>   significance.

Taken from [jewcology.com](http://www.jewcology.com/resource/The-Rainbow-and-an-Ethic-of-Sustainability)

Comment: Not that I am one to question the sforno but the text reads on 9:17 "זאת הקשת השניה" -- is this necessarily a double rainbow, or simply a second rainbow?

Comment: The Seforno holds that the rainbow already existed as part of creation, and so the rainbow which is referred to in parshas Noach is the **second** rainbow, the fainter rainbow whose colors are in the reverse order of the main rainbow. This is the double rainbow that the OP refers to. (See the Seforno on posuk 13, and also the Artscroll Seforno for a full explanation).

Comment: @GeminiMan thank you - I see kfula there. I appreciate the citation!

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10071/603