# Is it a bad sign for me personally if I saw a rainbow?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rainbows

[A rainbow is generally considered to be Hashem sending us a message that He is remembering his promise not to destroy the world, but implying that otherwise He would be destroying it.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/rainbow-as-a-bad-omen)

However, when a rainbow appears, most people don't tend to notice it.  Does that imply anything bad (or good?) for me personally that I saw it or we say that it is a global problem so it isn't personal?  Are there sources which discuss this?

Comment: Rainbows are present constantly somewhere.

Comment: But does a rainbow count if there is no one to see it?

Comment: Some teach that every thing one experiences is a directly crafted experience (with a message most likely) from Hashem https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/3317475/jewish/24-Elul.htm אַמאָל אִיז יעֶדעֶר וואָרט וואָס מ'האָט געֶהעֶרט געֶוועֶן אַ תּוֹרָה, אוּן יעֶדעֶר זאַךְ וואָס מ'האָט געֶזעֶהן — אַ הוֹרָאָה אִין עֲבוֹדָה אוּן הַדְרָכָה.