# What Blessing Does One Make on a Solar Eclipse?

Tags: halacha, blessing, astronomy

What Blessing Does One Make on a Solar Eclipse?  I will be in Nevada next week and would like to make a blessing over the May 21 Solar Eclipse.  Thanks!

Comment: Please upload pictures when you come back :)

Comment: So many requests. Here's one more: Please be mindful of the warning that appears when your mouse hovers over the `halacha` tag above: "Like Wikipedia, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends."

Comment: To All... Thanks for suggestions on the website use! I am new to the site.  @Double AA, I will see if I can upload some cool photos!

Comment: @PesachDavid How'd it go?

Comment: @DoubleAA, sorry I missed your comment.  It went great.  It was quite a spectacle.  The desert was amazing.  It is easy to see how great spiritual revelation can occur in the desert.

Comment: Here is a good comprehensive article about the solar eclipse: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3727131/jewish/Does-Judaism-See-Solar-Eclipses-As-Bad-Omens.htm

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Orchot Rabbeinu* 1 p 93 quotes the [Steipler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steipler) that no bracha is said on a solar eclipse because it is a Siman Ra', a bad omen as outlined on [Sukkah 29a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=29&format=pdf) and in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/eclipse-of-the-moon-bad-sign-for-the-jews).

In the book [Shaar HaAyin](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?161255) (7:6 footnote 13), the author quotes the [Shevet HaLevi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmuel_Wosner) as leaving the issue in doubt.

Comment: I had heard that an eclipse of the moon is a Siman Ra' for Israel, and that an eclipse of the sun is a Simon Ra' for the Nations.  For myself, I simply want to acknowledge the perfection of Hashem's creation, as revealed through an eclipse.   If there is no specific blessing, would it be improper to make a "...oseh ma-aseh b'reisheit"?

Comment: @PesachDavid The discussions involved in the sources I posted are precisely about if Oseh Maaseh Vereishit can be extended to natural events which are not explicitly list in the gemara. I don't think anyone thought there was a unique bracha to say, as none is mentioned in the gemara.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my own research into *Birkath Hachama* and *Kiddush Levanah* and building on [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84853/5127), I suggest the following:

After the end of totality (or after peak eclipse if you are not in the umbra's path), recite the three psalms used in both ceremonies:

- Ps. 148, v. 1 through 6.
- Ps. 121 (for supplication)
- Ps. 150

Then the entire first bracha of the weekday shaharit, from "yotzeir or u'vorei choshech" through "yotzeir hame'orot."

If a minyan is present and it is time to recite minchah, continue directly with minchah.

Finally, as soon as permitted (normally the 3rd day of the new month after sunset), recite *Kiddush Levanah*.

Disclaimer: IANAR, this is lay opinion, practice proper eclipse safety.

Comment: I’ve also heard Tehillim 19 (“hashamayim misaprim kevod Keil”) and Keil Adon (“tovim me’oros shebara Elokeinu”) should be said.

Comment: As far as Kiddush Levanah, do note that it’s a machlokes in the poskim whether we count by the solar eclipse or the calculated molad. Also note that we try to delay until Motzaei Shabbos, which is after 3 days from either count.

Comment: @DonielF: What would be a better phrasing?

Comment: @doniel that machloket is only about the end time for kiddush levana. You can say kiddush levana as soon as you see the moon [and some say when you see it and benefit from its light]

Comment: @DoubleAA I’m well aware. That’s why I worded it how I did - “we try” to delay. Not “we delay.”