# Shooting Stars and Luck

Tags: astronomy, superstition, natural-phenomenon

There seems to be a non-Jewish association of good luck with seeing a shooting star. Is there any source for this in Judaism?

Comment: One says a blessing when seeing it (שכחו וגבורתו מלא עולם), but see Isaiah 47, 13 about the idea of associating luck or making a wish etc.

Comment: Perhaps there is a connection with the word "Mazal" that means both "luck" and "constellation". Scientifically, we now know that meteors come from the asteroid belt. But on Earth, they appear to emanate (radiate) from constellations. Common meteor showers are usually named after constellation such as "Leonid" and "Gemini" meteors.

Comment: @DanF They don't come from the asteroid belt. Maybe the Oort cloud.

Comment: @doubleaa I think you're confusing meteors with comets. See http://www.amnh.org/exhibitions/permanent-exhibitions/earth-and-planetary-sciences-halls/arthur-ross-hall-of-meteorites/meteorites/what-is-a-meteorite/where-do-meteorites-come-from

Comment: @Yoni Meteors (ie vid) come from comet trails (for the most part, at least). You are confusing meteors and meteorites I think.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5111/11052

Comment: @DoubleAA not sure where you're getting your info..there's no difference between meteors and meteorites except whether it's moving through earth's atmosphere or hit earth. see https://www.google.com/search?q=meteors+vs+meteorites (But you're correct that _some_ meteoroids come from comets, but usually they come from the asteroids)

Comment: @Yoni My point is of the big ones that make it to earth, perhaps most are asteroid chunks. But when you go see a meteor shower in the sky it's from the orbit of a comet. That's why it's consistent. Look up "parent comets" of different meteor showers

Comment: Is this on topic? Seems like comparative religion.